# Custom Gallery Image Picker

Tags: java, android

I would like to allow the user to pock only one image that can be referenced via a uri, I've successfully done this through the following code:

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private Uri imageUri;

// Choose file extended from BottomTabView, opens all images on device
public static void openFileChooser(Context context) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

  // Slide Animation
  ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.nothing);

}

// TODO: Is it better to use bitmap or URI
// Check if user has selected file and describe next step
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    // Retrieve image as a URI
    imageUri = data.getData();

    // Pass image URI to an intent and start activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadImageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
    startActivity(intent);

    // Slide Animation
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    this.finish();
  }
}
```

The above code opens the following:

[image: General Gallery]

However, I would like to have something like the following:

[image: Custom Gallery]

**Question:** How can I achieve something more like the "Custom Gallery"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to custom layout pick image, you need:

- create a screen and using recyclerView to make the layout as you want
- get all picture gallery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957752/10153377)